# R - Shiny - Export DataTable with multiline cells to PDF (and Excel)

Tags: r, excel, shiny, datatables, dt

I have a table with multiline cells which display ok on the screen, but I cannot save the same format into a PDF or Excel files.

The solution described
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64452761/dtdatatable-export-to-pdf-while-preserving-html-br-for-multiline-cells) uses (a) an external application (but I may not be able to use it in shinyapps.io) and (b) also refers to kable (but the reference link does not save into a PDF file). I guess there must be a simpler solution than relying on such a cocktail of applications.

I include below a reprex with two buttons that save the table as PDF. With the first button I tried a rather standard procedure with *DT*, and with another button I tried *huxtable*. Both produce the same results when they create the PDF, that is, no multilines and no extra formatting (like **bold**). I would like to see in the PDF the same formatting that I see on the screen.

By the way, is it possible to have a similar solution (with multilines and formatting) exporting to Excel, in addition to PDFs? After all, Excel allows formatting inside cells, and they can also be multilines.

Thanks

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(huxtable)

data <- data.frame(
  Name = c("Mr A", "Mrs B"),
  Description = c("This is line 1.<br>Line 2.",
                  "This is another cell with line 1.<br>Line 2 has some <b>bold text</b>.")
)


ui <- dashboardPage(skin = "black",
                    dashboardHeader(disable = TRUE),
                    dashboardSidebar(disable = TRUE),
                    dashboardBody(DT::dataTableOutput("Table"),
                                  br(),
                                  actionButton("mytable_pdf", "huxtable PDF")
                    )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  output$Table <- DT::renderDataTable(data,
                                      extensions = 'Buttons',
                                      rownames   = FALSE,
                                      options = list(
                                        paging = FALSE,
                                        searching = TRUE,
                                        fixedColumns = TRUE,
                                        autoWidth = TRUE,
                                        ordering = TRUE,
                                        dom = '<Bt>', 
                                        pageLength=2,
                                        buttons = 'pdf'),  
                                      # buttons = c('excel','pdf')),
                                      escape = FALSE,
                                      class = "display"
)
   observeEvent(input$mytable_pdf, quick_pdf(data, file = "output.pdf"))
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: (1) Exporting to pdf -- especially with DT formatting -- is a question I've researched over the years and found nothing. I suggest you make (another) feature-request of the DT maintainers (the javascript-DT seems the more appropriate channel). (2) Look into `openxlsx`, though there's nothing automatic, you'll need to do a lot of it yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution for the multilines (found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58873629/1100107)). It works for PDF as well as Excel. For the bold font I have absolutely no idea.

```r
library(shiny)
library(DT)

js <- JS(
  "function(data, column, row) {",
  "  if(typeof data === 'string' || data instanceof String) {",
  "    data = data.replace(/<br\\s*\\/?>/ig, '\\r\\n');",
  "  }",
  "  return data;",
  "}"
)

dat <- data.frame(
  Name = c(
    "Mr A", "Mrs B"
  ),
  Description = c(
    "This is line 1.<br>Line 2.",
    "This is another cell with line 1.<br>Line 2 has some <b>bold text</b>."
  )
)

ui <- fluidPage(
  br(), br(),
  DTOutput("dtable")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  output[["dtable"]] <- renderDT({
    datatable(
      dat, escape = FALSE,
      extensions = "Buttons",
      options = list(
        dom = "Bfrtip",
        buttons = list(
          list(
            extend   = "pdf", 
            filename = "test",
            text     = "Save as PDF",
            exportOptions = list(
              format = list(
                body = js
              )
            )
          ),
          list(
            extend   = "excel", 
            filename = "test",
            text     = "Save as XLSX",
            exportOptions = list(
              format = list(
                body = js
              )
            )
          )
        )
      )
    )
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]