# Datatable.net Built in styles for word wrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am using Datatable.net and wanted my excel export to word wrap. I have tried using  $(this).attr('s', 55); like this https://datatables.net/reference/button/excelHtml5#Built-in-styles. I have also tried setting the width and seeing if that helps. I have also tried added "  but nothing has been working.

JS Code

```
$(tableId).DataTable({
    "lengthMenu": [
       [10, 15, 20, -1],
       [10, 15, 20, "All"]
     ],
    "pageLength": -1,
    scrollX: true,
    buttons: [
    {
       extend: 'excelHtml5',
       title: "Individual Report - " + moment().format('MM-DD-YYYY'),
           customize: function (xlsx) {
              var sheet = xlsx.xl.worksheets["sheet1.xml"];
              var col = $("col", sheet);
              col.each(function () {
                 $(this).attr('s', 55);
                 $(this).attr('width', 33);
              });

        }
     }
   ]
 );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The selector you are using for the built-in style needs to be adjusted from this:

```
$(this).attr('s', 55);
```

to this:

```
$('row c', sheet).attr( 's', '55' );
```

The `$("col", sheet)` selector is for the `<cols>` tags in the worksheet XML - for example:

```
<cols>
    <col min="1" max="1" width="18.85546875" customWidth="1"/>
    <col min="2" max="2" width="24.28515625" customWidth="1"/>
</cols>
```

That is correct for setting widths.

But for the style `s` attribute, you need to target the `<c>` tag - for example:

```
<row r="2" spans="1:2">
    <c r="A2" t="s">
        <v>2</v>
    </c>
    <c r="B2" t="s">
        <v>3</v>
    </c>
</row>
```

Here is some demo code (it doesn't generate an Excel in a Stack Snippet, so here is the core code):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var table = $('#example').DataTable( {
    dom: 'Bfrtip',
    buttons: [
      {
        extend: 'excelHtml5',
        text: 'Save as Excel',
        title: '',
        customize: function( xlsx ) {
          var sheet = xlsx.xl.worksheets['sheet1.xml'];
          $('row c', sheet).attr( 's', '55' );
          var col = $("col", sheet);
          col.each(function () {
            $(this).attr('width', 15);
          });
        }
      }
    ]
  } );

} );
```

The end result (with my test data):

[image]

Comment: Thanks this is working great another problem is that I have <br> and I been trying to replace with a line break

Comment: Do you mean something like this: [line break when exporting to excel Datatable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54081794/12567365)? Or any of [these similar questions](https://www.google.com/search?q=datatables+export+line+break+site:stackoverflow.com)? If none of those work for you (or if they are not what you are trying to do), you can ask a new question and show us your attempt.

Comment: I changed the width to be 75 but can this be auto size base the length of the data? some columns just have a date time and I would not need that to have a width of 75

Comment: You can ask a new question for this. That way, many more community members will see your question, increasing your chances of getting a good answer.

Comment: I created a new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76334964/datatable-net-export-to-excel-autofit-width