# Datatable.net export to excel autofit width

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am building this report in html and then have a option to export the data into excel. I have it setup for word wrap which is now working but all the columns are 75 width. Can this be base on the data length? or can I use some type of autofit width?

```
$("#Report").DataTable({
       paging: false,
       scrollX: true,
       order: [[3, 'asc']],
       buttons: [
           {
            extend: 'excelHtml5',
            title: "Report - " + moment().format('MM-DD-YYYY'),
            exportOptions: {
                 stripHtml: false,
                 stripNewlines: false,
                 format: {
                    body: function (data, column, row) {
                    return data.replace(/<br\s*\/?>/ig, "\n")
                               .replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig, "");
                    }
                  }
                  },
                  customize: function (xlsx) {
                    var sheet = xlsx.xl.worksheets['sheet1.xml'];
                    $('row c', sheet).attr('s', '55');
                    var col = $("col", sheet);
                    col.each(function () {
                         $(this).attr('width', 75);
                    });
                    }
                  }
                ]
      });
```